# Encrypt with CryptoJS.. Decrypt with Node Crypto lib

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, node-crypto

I'm trying to do a simple encryption with Crypto.js and then do the decryption with the Node.js crypto library.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')

const message = 'Hello World'
const key = '3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY'
const iv = '655478daef95fdae'

const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {
  iv: iv,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
})

const encryptedString = encrypted.toString()

const cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv)
let decrypted = cipher.update(encryptedString, 'base64', 'utf8')
decrypted += cipher.final('utf8')

console.log(decrypted)
```

The call to `cipher.final('utf8')` gives the error:

`Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

As far as I've seen, this error is related to the key being wrong but I don't understand how that could be the case here.

Comment: I think the first one has 128-key size, the second one 256.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  Is the value of `encryptedString` what you think it is?  Print out each of the iv, key and plaintext/ciphertext and ensure everything lines up.

Comment: @sean, I am facing the same issue as well. were you able to resolve this issue? We have to encrypt using "crypto-js" and decrypt using "crypto" which is not working right now.